# Android/Java, получить Unix timestamp от даты

Tags: android, unixtimestamp, java

Здравствуйте,

С помощью следующего кода, я получаю текущее время в определенной временной зоне:

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));

String time = sdf.format(new Date()); / *20/02/2014 00:50:15* /

Никак не могу найти четкий ответ на то: Как мне от полученного времени, получить [Unix timestamp](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F) ?

Comment: Unix timestamp:

    long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;


Или я чего-то не пойму? )

Comment: Да, в вашем примере получаем текущее системное время. 
А мне нужно именно в определенной временной зоны (в примере московское время)
Как видно из примера, я нашел как получать время в каком либо формате в нужной временной зоны, но как получить Unix timestamp. В этом и проблема :)

Получается к примеру, нужен некий аналог функции strtotime из PHP к примеру

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sdf.parse(sdf.format(new Date())).getTime()

:)